# Different form in different tab android

Tags: android, android-tabs

I have 2 tabs: Report and Profile.

I want to add a different form (Textview, spinner, etc) in each of the tabs. For now im trying with a button and it should be different button in different tab.

But what i get is i have the same button in both tab. It should show button name ButtonReport in Report Tab and ButtonProfile in Profile Tab.

Below is the picture of it.

[image]

I am putting the button code in main.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">



        <!-- Start Interface -->
        <TableLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="false">  
        <TableRow android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/tableRow3">
            <TableLayout android:id="@+id/tableLayout2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <Button android:text="Button Report" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>

            </TableLayout>
            </TableRow>     
        </TableLayout>
        <!-- End Interface -->


        </FrameLayout>



    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

This is my ReportActivity class and ProfileActivity(same code only different name)

```
package com.tab;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ReportActivity extends Activity{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView text = new TextView(this);
        text.setText("Artist");
        setContentView(text);
    }
}
```

This is my MainActivity class

```
package com.tab;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {
    private TabHost aTab;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Resources res = getResources();
        aTab = getTabHost();
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;
        Intent intent;

        //Report Tab
        intent = new Intent(this, ReportActivity.class);

        spec = aTab.newTabSpec("Report")
            .setIndicator("Report", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_icon))
            .setContent(intent);
        aTab.addTab(spec);

        //Profile Tab
        intent = new Intent(this, ProfileActivity.class);

        spec = aTab.newTabSpec("Profile")
            .setIndicator("Profile", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_icon))
            .setContent(intent);
        aTab.addTab(spec);

        aTab.setCurrentTab(1);
    }
}
```

is there a way to have different form in different tab?

Comment: What do you want? Different contents in these two tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way (my opinion) is to use Fragments :
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Fragment are for API Level 11 minimum, but you can work with a compatibility package :
http://android-developers.blogspot.ch/2011/03/fragments-for-all.html

So every tab will become a fragment.

Answer (score 1):

[Have a look at TabHost tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/) And, just look how they're using Different Contents in their `TabHost` For Example -

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

**Report.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <!-- Screen Design for Photos -->
  <Button android:text="Button Report"
            android:textSize="18dip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Profile.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <!-- Screen Design for Photos -->
  <Button android:text="Button Profile"
            android:textSize="18dip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

In your **main.xml** class contain some different thing that is **Start Interface** This is the problem that to display the same content `(Button)` is every tab. You've to remove this.

And, in your `Profile` and `Report` activities just view this `xml` file using `setContentView` This will provide the seperate buttons which you need. You can use `MainActivity` for this, it seems perfect.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: @sarabrown Yes, like that only. In each `Activity`(Profile & Report) use their xml files seperately with `setContentView(R.layout.profile)` and `setContentView(R.layout.report)`

Answer (score 1):

You can set different layout xml's for each activity (report and profile):
Source: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/
First make an activity called TabHostActivity:

```
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class TabHostActivity extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        TabSpec report = tabHost.newTabSpec("Report");
        report.setIndicator("Report", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_report));
        Intent reportIntent = new Intent(this, report.class);
        report.setContent(reportIntent);

TabSpec profile = tabHost.newTabSpec("Profile");
        profile.setIndicator("Profile", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_profile));
        Intent profileIntent = new Intent(this, profile.class);
        profile.setContent(profileIntent);


        // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
        tabHost.addTab(report); // Adding photos tab
        tabHost.addTab(profile); // Adding songs tab
    }
}
```

then make Main.xml under res/layouts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Then two different activities that will do your actions for report and profile:

```
//report.java
package com.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ReportActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.report_layout);
    }
}

//profile.java
package com.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ProfileActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.profile_layout);
    }
}
```

Now you can make your two XML's, one for the profile layout and one for the report layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TextView android:text="Profile"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:textSize="18dip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TextView android:text="Report"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:textSize="18dip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Once that is done you can modify each xml to have whatever buttons and spinners, etc. you like.

Lastly, make sure you modify your AndroidManifest to allow the activities and auto-launch via the intent filters to your tabhostactivity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".TabHostActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".profile" />

        <activity android:name=".report" />


    </application>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this piece of code will help you.You can use different intents to call different tab activity..And you can set different content views to different activities..

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Resources ressources = getResources(); 
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        //Setting Android TAB
        Intent intentAndroid = new Intent().setClass(this, AndroidTab.class);
        TabSpec tabSpecAndroid = tabHost
          .newTabSpec("Android")
          .setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.android))
          .setContent(intentAndroid);

        //Setting Apple TAB
        Intent intentApple = new Intent().setClass(this, AppleActivity.class);
        TabSpec tabSpecApple = tabHost
          .newTabSpec("Apple")
          .setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.aapl))
          .setContent(intentApple);



        //Add all tabs
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpecAndroid);
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpecApple);


        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
}
}
```

After you should create different classes and make two activities for android and apple.In that particular activities you can set different contentviews and I think you will get what you wanted.This is just a sample you can make it what you want as the same..